# Excel VBA: Splitting a row into multiple rows

Tags: vba, excel

I have a row of cells that contains data that needs to be turned into multiple rows.

> 18-Apr-17 11:00:30    SkyFlyer1_Leg1  319437.222  146279.951  -32.768 SkyFlyer1_Leg2  319417.07   146268.105  -32.768 SkyFlyer1_Leg3  319410.548  146268.368  -32.768

This is half of one line (there are 8 legs). The spaces indicate deliminations between the cells.

Each "SkyFlyer_Leg*" needs a carrage return to take it onto a new line.

These lines are being brought into the worksheet using another script that is parsing them from a CSV.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CSVParser_99()

Dim i As Long
Dim x As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim PasteRow As Long

   With Sheets("CSV Paste")
        LastRow = .Range("A3").End(xlDown).Row
        For i = 3 To LastRow
            PasteRow = Sheets("Working Sheet 1").Cells(Sheets("Working Sheet 1").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        .Range(.Range("A" & i), .Range("A" & i).End(xlToRight)).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Working Sheet 1").Range("A" & PasteRow + 1)

        Call RowDiv

    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

---

```
Sub RowDiv()

Dim Row1 As Variant

With Sheets("Working Sheet 1")
    .Range("C6000").End(xlUp).Select
End With

With Row1.ActiveCell

End With

End Sub
```

This is what I have got so far, including the script that brings the code into this page. (Thanks to Shai Rado for the help so far)

The result I want would have the data arranged like:

> 18-Apr-17|    11:00:30
>
> SkyFlyer1_Leg1|   319437.222| 146279.951| -32.768
>
> SkyFlyer1_Leg2|   319417.070| 146268.105| -32.768
>
> SkyFlyer1_Leg3|   319410.548| 146268.368| -32.768

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers, J

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would work

```
Sub CSVParser_99()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim x As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim PasteRow As Long

       With Sheets("CSV Paste")
            LastRow = .Range("A3").End(xlDown).Row
            For i = 3 To LastRow
                PasteRow = Sheets("Working Sheet 1").Cells(Sheets("Working Sheet 1").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            .Range(.Range("A" & i), .Range("A" & i).End(xlToRight)).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Working Sheet 1").Range("A" & PasteRow + 1)

            Call RowDiv

        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

```
Sub RowDiv()

    Dim Row1 As Range

    With Sheets("Working Sheet 1")
        Set Row1 = .Range("A6000").End(xlUp)
    End With

    With Row1

        .TextToColumns Destination:=ActiveCell, DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, _
            Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
            :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), _
            Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1), Array(11, 1), Array(12, 1), Array(13, 1 _
            ), Array(14, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the help, but this doesn't seem to do anything at all. I think that the TextToColumn function won't work as the data is already seperated into columns and I need a carrige return. Cheers J

Comment: I copy paste your data into directly an excel sheet as you didn't mention column separators. So if it's already into column, loop from the last row, copy the data you need, insert the number of rows you need and copy the data there, then move one row up

Comment: The problem is, I do not know how to loop through the last row. Do you know the code for this?